# Make division by zero equal to zero

Tags: python, division, zero

How can I ignore `ZeroDivisionError` and make `n / 0 == 0`?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: I am dividing by a variable that could be 0.

Comment: Just do keep in mind that the correct result of dividing a variable by 0 is *not* 0.

Comment: @wds Sometimes, "correct" is just a synonym for "what I want it to be" ;)

Comment: At instruction level in ARM64 `x/0` results in 0 so a simple `x/y` would work. But I don't know how Python is compiled to machine code

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Check if the denominator is zero before dividing.  This avoids the overhead of catching the exception, which may be more efficient if you expect to be dividing by zero a lot.

```
def weird_division(n, d):
    return n / d if d else 0
```

Answer (score 51):

### Solution

When you want to efficient handle `ZeroDivisionError` (division by zero) then you should not use exceptions or conditionals.

```python
result = b and a / b or 0  # a / b
```

### How it's works?

- When `b != 0` we have `True and a / b or 0`. `True and a / b` is equal to `a / b`. `a / b or 0` is equal to `a / b`.
- When `b == 0` we have `False and a / b or 0`. `False and a / b` is equal to `False`. `False or 0` is equal to `0`.

### Benchmark

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 118.362 s
File: benchmark.py
Function: exception_div at line 3

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     3                                           @profile
     4                                           def exception_div(a, b):
     5 100000000   23419098.5      0.2     19.8      try:
     6 100000000   40715642.9      0.4     34.4          return a / b
     7 100000000   28910860.8      0.3     24.4      except ZeroDivisionError:
     8 100000000   25316209.7      0.3     21.4          return 0

Total time: 23.638 s
File: benchmark.py
Function: conditional_div at line 10

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    10                                           @profile
    11                                           def conditional_div(a, b):
    12 100000000   23638033.3      0.2    100.0      return a / b if b else 0

Total time: 23.2162 s
File: benchmark.py
Function: logic_div at line 14

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    14                                           @profile
    15                                           def logic_div(a, b):
    16 100000000   23216226.0      0.2    100.0      return b and a / b or 0
```

Comment: This is an absolutely fantastic answer. It should be the top upvoted one, thanks for sharing this nifty trick!

Comment: The answer is great, but it seems `or 0` is redundant. `type(0 and 1) == int` , not `bool`.

Answer (score 45):

You can use a `try`/`except` block for this.

```
def foo(x,y):
    try:
        return x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

>>> foo(5,0)
0

>>> foo(6,2)
3.0
```

Answer (score 20):

I think `try` `except` (as in Cyber's answer) is usually the best way (and more pythonic: better to ask forgiveness than to ask permission!), but here's another:

```
def safe_div(x,y):
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    return x / y
```

One argument in favor of doing it this way, though, is if you expect `ZeroDivisionError`s to happen often, checking for 0 denominator ahead of time will be a lot faster (this is python 3):

```
import time

def timing(func):
    def wrap(f):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = func(f)
        time2 = time.time()
        print('%s function took %0.3f ms' % (f.__name__, int((time2-time1)*1000.0)))
        return ret
    return wrap

def safe_div(x,y):
    if y==0: return 0
    return x/y

def try_div(x,y):
    try: return x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError: return 0

@timing
def test_many_errors(f):
    print("Results for lots of caught errors:")
    for i in range(1000000):
        f(i,0)

@timing
def test_few_errors(f):
    print("Results for no caught errors:")
    for i in range(1000000):
        f(i,1)

test_many_errors(safe_div)
test_many_errors(try_div)
test_few_errors(safe_div)
test_few_errors(try_div)
```

Output:

```
Results for lots of caught errors:
safe_div function took 185.000 ms
Results for lots of caught errors:
try_div function took 727.000 ms
Results for no caught errors:
safe_div function took 223.000 ms
Results for no caught errors:
try_div function took 205.000 ms
```

So using `try` `except` turns out to be 3 to 4 times slower for lots of (or really, all) errors; that is: it is 3 to 4 times slower *for iterations that an error is caught*. The version using the `if` statement turns out to be slightly slower (10% or so) when there are few (or really, no) errors.

Comment: `try except` will be slower when you end up in the `except` clause more often. In this case, always. If you know that only about 1 in 1000 times, you get a division by 0, `try except` will be faster. So your test is only relevant for a minimal subset of cases.

Comment: Edited to illustrate your point. I was surprised that it's only a 10% or so slow down to check for 0, though. Error handling is slower than I realized.

Comment: @RickTeachey The overhead of checking is so small relatively because the cost is ~90%+ function call overhead.

Comment: Makes sense. Catching an error is in essence another function call.

Answer (score 12):

```
def foo(x, y):
    return 0 if y == 0 else x / y
```

Comment: I'm just curious. Why did the other answers get more votes than this one? I understand Cyber's getting more, but the other 2 are equivalent to this.

Comment: Hmm, normally I would use that method in `if` statements. But in this case I'd rather be explicit about not wanting y to be equal to 0. I prefer the way it reads when read out as a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you don't want to face Zer0DivErrr, you haven't got to wait for it or go through it by using try-except expression. The quicker way is to jump over it by making your code simply not to do division when denominator becomes zero:

```
(if Y Z=X/Y else Z=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to divide two integers you may use :

```
if y !=0 :
   z = x/y
else:
    z = 0
```

or you can use :

```
z = ( x / y ) if y != 0 else 0
```

If you are trying to divide two lists of integers you may use :

```
z = [j/k if k else 0 for j, k in zip(x, y)]
```

where here, x and y are two lists of integers.

Answer (score 2):

As simple as it gets:

```
def safe_division(numerator, denominator):
    """Return 0 if denominator is 0."""
    return denominator and numerator / denominator
```

[`and`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) returns either zero `denominator` or the result of the division.

Bytecode:

```
In [51]: dis(safe_division)
 25           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (denominator)
              2 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP     5 (to 10)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (numerator)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (denominator)
              8 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
        >>   10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Returning zero `denominator` removes the need to load zero with `LOAD_CONST`.

---

If you don't mind rolling up the sleeves to get a little bit more performance, here is a C++ version:

```cpp
static inline double div_positive_or_0(double a, double b) noexcept {
    // Convert the quotient of division by non-positive numbers to 0.
    // vpandpd turns quotient to 0 without branches.
    // Using Intel intrinsincs to convert double to __m128d involves extra register copies.
    // Use inline assembly to avoid unnecessary register copying.
    a /= b;
    asm("vcmpltsd %[b], %[z], %[b] \n\t" // b = zero < b
        "vandpd %[a], %[a], %[b]"        // a &= b
        : [a]"+v"(a),[b]"+v"(b)
        : [z]"v"(0)
        : );
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
x=0,y=0
print (y/(x or not x))
```

Output:

```
>>>x=0
>>>y=0
>>>print(y/(x or not x))
0.0
>>>x =1000
>>>print(y/(x or not x))
0.000999000999000999
```

not x will be false if x is not equal to 0, so at that time it divides with actual x.

Comment: The OP wants the outcome to be `0` not `1.0`, so already you first example doesn't meet the OP's needs.

Comment: I have kept y as 1, just make it zero, you should get 0.0. But thank you, I just edited my ans.

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued why [ToTomire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15964568/totamire)'s solution would be faster. If feels like `conditional_div` should often be preferred for its natural language readability, but if I can understand exactly why `logic_div` is faster that might help me in the future. I looked to python's `dis` for this.

```py
>>> conditional_div = lambda n,d: n/d if d else 0
>>> logic_div = lambda n,d: d and n/d or 0
>>> dis.dis(conditional_div)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
              8 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
             10 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(logic_div)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
              8 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
             10 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     14
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

And it appears that `logic_div` should actually have an extra step. Up to '8' the two bytecodes are identical. At '10' `conditional_div` would just return a value whereas `logic_div` has to do a jump if its true and then return. Perhaps the alternative `..._OR_POP` is faster than returning so some percent of the time it has a shorter last step? But the only way that `..._OR_POP` would be activated is if the numerator were zero and the denominator non-zero. Both bytecodes take the same route when the denominator is zero. This doesn't feel like a satisfying conclusion. Maybe someone can explain if I'm misunderstanding something.

For reference

```
>>> sys.version
'3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Comment: Did you also replicate @ToTomire's benchmarking to check that it is actually faster under your system specs? The speed difference is tiny and I think repeated trials are needed to determine the significance level of the difference.