# How to return 0 with divide by 0 from string?

Tags: python, string

I have a string like `8/c123*c456` where `c123` and `c456` are variables containing a float. I use Regex to separate the string into a list `['8', '/', 'c123', '*', 'c456']`. I replace `'c123'` and `'c456'` with a string corresponding to their value (like `'4.0'` for example). I then concatenate the string and try to evaluate it using the class NumericStringParser from this question ([Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)).

The problem is when the value of one of the variables is 0 and I end up trying to divide by 0 in the operation. I would like that operation to return 0.

I saw the answers from this question [Make division by zero equal to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317517/make-division-by-zero-equal-to-zero) but I don't know how I can use them.

Comment: Please provide the code you are working.

Comment: Simply check if `'c123'` or `'c456'` is equal to zero before dividing.

Comment: Not sure that would work, but I could actually check with regex if the concatenated string contains /0. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
try:
  #Your operation here
except ZeroDivisionError:
  # return 0 here
```

More information here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Exceptions